# DIV in the form and post them on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="MG_TextBox" contenteditable="true" name="textBox1" style="width:600px;height:400px; background-color:#ECCBCB;"> Hello</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="MH_Hiddeninput" >
    <input type="submit" id="MG_Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

And ajax

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#MG_Submit').click(function () {
        var MG_Text = $('#MG_TextBox').html();
        $('#MG_Hiddeninput').val(MG_Text);
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

then php

```
<?
    if ($_POST['hiddeninput'])  {
        print $_POST['hiddeninput'];
        }
?>
```

I would like to have transferred DIV content to HIDDEN INPUT. Subsequently PHP to print them on the same page. ie. action = ""

what am I doing wrong?

Version 2. still not work

```
<?
if ($_POST['hiddeninput'])  { print $_POST['hiddeninput']; }
?>

<html>
<head> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#MG_Form').on("submit", function (e) {
        var MG_Text = $('#MG_TextBox').html();
        $('#MG_Hiddeninput').val(MG_Text);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post" id="MG_Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="MG_TextBox" contenteditable="true" name="textBox1" style="width:300px;height:200px; background-color:
    #9AB5BF;"> Hello</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="MG_Hiddeninput" >
    <input type="submit" id="MG_Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: php cannot do anything to a currently loaded page. also note you dont have any ajax shown, all that is shown below the _"And ajax"_ is a click event handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't want the form to submit, you want the AJAX to fire instead. Do this to stop the click from doing its default behaviour - which would submit the form;

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('form').on("submit", function (e) {
        var MG_Text = $('#MG_TextBox').html();
        $('#MG_Hiddeninput').val(MG_Text);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

You may want to add an `id` to the form, so that the `$('form')` selector can be more specific. As this might currently break other forms on the page.

Answer (score 0):

for starters, you're trying to select an element that doesn't exist (MG_Hiddeninput). Change to this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#MG_Submit').click(function () {
        var MG_Text = $('#MG_TextBox').html();
        $('#MH_Hiddeninput').val(MG_Text);
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

or change the id of your hidden input to match your selector.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="MG_Hiddeninput" >
```

also add e.preventDefault() to prevent form from posting. you mention ajax but i don't see any in action here.